# $\iint_{S} z+y+\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)} \,ds$ , surface integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

$$\iint_{S} z+y+\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)}   \,ds$$

$$ S: x^2+y^2=a^2,0\leqslant z     
\leqslant       c   $$

$$ a,c>0 $$

Evaluate surface integral.

I wanted to express x(y),then with it evaluate $ dS $, then project this on yOz. The limits of y would be from - a to a, z from 0 to c.
I have seen  a solution in which $ dS $ was calculated from y. And the integral  was divide into 2 parts for positive and negative y.

Is my idea okay?

Comment: I think you may want to think about what your surface is carefully, and think if there is another coordinate system which may make your life easier first (it may also help parametrizing the surface and seeing the outward normal as well)...

Comment: @mathematics2x2life are u talking about cylindrical? I dont how to use cylindirical when dealing with surface integrals, how do i then find dS

Comment: There are formulas for this if you dont want to derive them yourself. See here: http://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes02/v9.pdf. If you don't yet know this, then you can do this directly and it's not too terrible. Just given the integrand and the surface, cylindrical coordinates seemed natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds right to me. We can then express the integral as following$$I=\iint_Sz+y+|y|ds=\iint_{y>0}z+2yds+\iint_{y<0}zds$$where$$ds=ad\phi dz$$therefore $$I=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{\pi}z+2a\sin\phi ad\phi dz+2a\pi\int_{0}^{a}zdz$$

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: You're welcome hope it helps